# Scroll to absolutely positioned elements inside a relatively positioned div

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a weird edge case where a legacy document had some elements that are absolutely positioned inside a div that is relatively positioned. These elements have a negative value for the `left` css attribute.

```
.container {
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}

.element {
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     background: red;
}
```

Now two questions:

1. Is it possible to setup `container` to scroll and show the negatively positioned elements?
2. If not, how should I go about fixing the negative elements so that all the remaining elements shift accordingly?

**Here is an example JSBin:** http://jsbin.com/xolifotiku/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Can you explain more about what you trying to achieve? May be some dummy layout picture.

Comment: @maximelian1986 I have added a jsbin example...hopefully that would help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.element').offset().top
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 500px;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 50px 20px 20px 20px;
}
.element {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: -20px;
  left: 0px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more close to the scenario that I am dealing with...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollLeft: $('.element').offset().left
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 500px;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 50px 20px 20px 20px;
}
.element {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: -20px;
  left: -100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.element').offset().top
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 500px;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 50px 20px 20px 20px;
}
.element {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: -20px;
  left: 0px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```